# Access beyond end of merge section with gcc

Tags: linux, gcc

while doing a POC on AWS environment for my build environment i found following errors

```
[703/704] Linking build/unittest/ut/deps/UnitTestDeps.o
[704/704] Linking build/unittest/ut/CaiFrameLssTest_Linux
/bin/ld: ColorCodeMacMsg.cpp.1.o: access beyond end of merged section (1503501432)
/bin/ld: ColorCodeMacMsg.cpp.1.o: access beyond end of merged section (4199896184)
/bin/ld: ColorCodeMacMsg.cpp.1.o: access beyond end of merged section (558823358)
/bin/ld: ColorCodeMacMsg.cpp.1.o: access beyond end of merged section (541297024)
/bin/ld: ColorCodeMacMsg.cpp.1.o: access beyond end of merged section (2437239330)
/bin/ld: ColorCodeMacMsg.cpp.1.o: access beyond end of merged section (1549026642)
<<Cropped>>
error 2
/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm using RHEL 7.4 environment and gcc 4.8.5

Can you please help me to identify what else missing with install